# How can I access and sort lists within lists in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a large array with which I would like to sort. In the array, the first item in the array is the category, and the second item is the item that needs to be sorted. For example:

```
joe = [['miles', 330], ['points', 5000], ['miles', 400], ['points', 4000], ['trophy', 'explorer'], ['points', 4100]]
```

I've been trying different ways to access the lists within the lists, but I'm not sure how I can do this exactly. How can I access the information?

I've tried variations on:

```
mylist = []
for item in joe:
    category = mylist(item[0])
    print category
```

Afterwards I would assign these values to different arrays (I'm supposed to have 3 separate arrays and sort that data essentially). My main concern right now though is what is the best way to assign the data.

Comment: I'm confused.  What should the output look like when you're done?

Comment: it looks like you should have been using a `dict` earlier in your code

Comment: @mgilson, the output at the end would simply be a printout of the 3 arrays. from what I have, I need to create 3 arrays, one for trophies, one for points, and one for miles. Just a printout of the three new separate arrays. And I'm afraid I don't understand quite what you suggested :(

Comment: @pearbear -- A `dict` is a dictionary and it is a mapping object.  It takes one object as a "key" and returns a "value".  They're super useful for all sorts of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this loop:

```
for item in joe:
```

What does `item` look like? No need to guess, you can print it:

```
for item in joe:
    print item
```

Clearly, `item` is each of the sublists within your main list, the first being `['miles', 330]`.

Now how do you get the `'miles'`?  `item[0]`, right?  `item[1]` would be `330`.

Now you can easily construct new lists based on the category. We'll store these in a dictionary.

```
joedict = {}
for item in joe:
    joedict.setdefault(item[0], []).append(item[1])
```

Now `joedict['miles']` is a list of all the miles and so on.

To sort each of these is straightforward:

```
for value in joedict.itervalues():
    value.sort()
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you!!! This was very helpful, I can't do the dictionary thing but I will use this information to help me with an if statement.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you want something like:

```
new_joe = sorted( joe,key = lambda x: x[1] )
```

which is the same thing as the slightly more efficient:

```
from operator import itemgetter
new_joe = sorted( joe, key = itemgetter(1) )
```

Or, you can sort `joe` in place:

```
joe.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

But, what if you want to have all of the `'miles'` lists together, and then sorted in ascending order after that?

```
joe.sort()
```

should do the trick ... (and now, hopefully I've covered enough bases that I hit the one you need).

---

Ahh, Now I see what you want.  For this, you have a bunch of options.  My favorite is a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in joe:
   d[k].append(v)

for k,v in d.items():
   print(k,v)
```

But another options would be to sort `joe` (e.g. `joe.sort()`) and use `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

To separate the data into lists for each category, a dictionary will help you - it can associate the single string with a list of numbers. So, start with a dict associating all your categories with an empty list - `my_dict = {'miles': [], 'points': []}` etc, and iterate over the list - at each item, you want to append the number to the list associated with the string:

```
for item in joe:
    category = item[0]
    my_dict[category].append(item[1])
```

You can avoid having to hard code (or precompute) all the categories to put in the dict by using the dict's `setdefault` method:

```
my_dict = {}
for item in joe:
   category = item[0]
   my_dict.setdefault(category, []).append(item[1])
```

To then sort each of these lists, you can just iterate over the dict's values and sort them in place using the list's `sort` method:

```
for category in my_dict:
   my_dict[category].sort()
```

This will give you a `my_dict` that looks like:

```
{'trophy': ['explorer'], 'miles': [330, 400], 'points': [4000, 4100, 5000]}
```

Comment: You could even use a `defaultdict(list)` for this if you don't know all the keys up front.

Comment: @mgilson indeed; but see also  http://twitter.com/raymondh/status/185818102968221698

Comment: I don't think I can use a dictionary, but thank you! We haven't really learned that and I don't think they want us to go ahead

Comment: @ivc -- I didn't know `setdefault` existed when I learned about `defaultdict` ... `get` maybe ...